# Delimiter string in Telit GL 868 Dual V3

Tags: modem

I am using `Telit modem GL 868 Dual V3`. AT command `AT#SCFG` has 2 parameters-  packet size to be used and data sending time-out for `TCP`. Is there any AT command which specifies that if any delimiter string is found, then that data will be sent on `TCP` ignoring the packet size and time-out?

Answer (score 0):

There are commands  #PADFWD, #PADCMD which serves the purpose of delimiter.

Below is a snapshot from AT commands reference guide for telit modem.

[image]